# Magento 2 How can i customize the product on the page Product Listing Page Widget of Live Search

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.4, custom-options

I am using
magento version  2.4.5
live search versions : * 3.0.1

How can I customize the product information displayed
[image]

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-merchant-services/live-search/live-search-storefront/plp-styling.html?lang=en

I want to display more brands and labels for products, how should I do it?

Comment: Have you figure it out? Every source I've come across mentions that it's a challenging task to deal with the js to customize, yet there are no available examples or guides on how to do it

Comment: Has Anyone succeded with this one?

Answer (score 2):

I am searching for information about LiveSearch commerce module.
I can see that the data is comming with GraphQL request that connected to the SaaS envierment you set up with "Commerce Services Connector" at admin panel.

if i will find more information about how can i apply mutations into this query i will update this post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know how to do similar things, but I haven't found any information...
I even asked a question similar to yours, in case anyone wants to help me!

[Magento 2 - Does anyone know how to customize the live search results with PLP Widget?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/372181/magento-2-does-anyone-know-how-to-customize-the-live-search-results-with-plp-w)