# Magento 2 - Does anyone know how to customize the live search results with PLP Widget?

Tags: magento2, magento-cloud

I'm looking for ways to change the Live Search query to show more information about the categories in the search results.
For example, show category banners or add a widget to the search results, such as a banner or product suggestion.
The problem is that I can't find any way to do this, no documentation at all. Has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: The PLP Repo is here with associated docs: https://github.com/adobe/storefront-product-listing-page The Search as you type is found here with associated docs: https://github.com/adobe/storefront-search-as-you-type